# Export selected converted geotagged photo points to a new feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.1, geotag, photos, attachments

I used the `GeoTagged Photos to Points` tool to convert a folder of geotagged photos to points, importing the photos into the file gdb as attachments. I now have a feature class of about 7 000 points.

I have selected 100 of the points and now need to put this into a new feature class in a different gdb. However, the points lose their attachments when exported to a different gdb, and copying the original attachment table to the new gdb results in all 7 000 being copied.

Trying to associated the match table with the new feature class using `Add Attachments` fails because the geotagged conversion tool automatically stores the image paths as relative not absolute. Is there a way for me to extract the selected photos along with their attached images to a new feature class?

Comment: I've added my workaround below, though I would still like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I have not tested but intuitively I would expect using the Select_analysis tool to do this with a Standard or Advanced license (Basic cannot write attachments because it cannot write relationship classes). Is that the method you tried?

Comment: I was manually selecting the points because visually I had to spread them also evenly across my study area, and I also had to check the photo quality before selecting the point, so I just did a normal export. Afterwards I tried a combo of joining to the attachment table/copying the table over, both of which did not work (wasn't really expecting it to). I will try the Select with a few test points now.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I used a search cursor to extract the paths of images from the points I selected, copied those images to a new folder, and then ran the geotagged photos tool on that.

Answer (score -1):

If using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 you can 'export to xml' and add the xml in the new GDB.